# Resize div background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I have to set background images (sprite pngs) within 3 divs. I need the pngs to resize with the div size as it's a fluid layout.

I've looked around for a solution to this and can only find solutions using `<img>` within the html. I appreciate this would be an easier way to deal with the situation but need to use background images. I need a solution for background images - not advice to use `<img>` please!

I realise that css3 offers a possible solution with background-size, but this does not help with IE7 & IE8 and other non-css3 browsers. I am very happy to use jquery, but can't think of how I might dynamically resize the pngs to fit the divs.

I'd really appreciate some assistance, but please understand that I'm unable to use `<img>`.

Here's my css:

```
a.bigButton {
height:30%;
width:30%;
display:block;
float:left;
}
a.bigButton#btn-menus:link {
background:url(images/btn-menus-large.png) top center no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
}
a.bigButton#btn-menus:hover {
background-position: -298px 0;
}
a.bigButton#btn-functions:link {
background:url(images/btn-functions-large.png) top center no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
}
a.bigButton#btn-functions:hover {
background-position: -298px 0;
}
a.bigButton#btn-packages:link {
background:url(images/btn-av-large.png) top center no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
}
a.bigButton#btn-packages:hover {
background-position: -298px 0;
}
```

My html:

```
<div id="quick-links-holder">
<a href="#" alt="Check out our menus" class="scroll bigButton btnResize" id="btn-menus"></a>
<a href="#" alt="What function will you hold at Events Centre?" class="scroll bigButton btnResize addMargin" id="btn-functions"></a>
<a href="#" alt="Check out our functions and packages" class="scroll bigButton btnResize addMargin" id="btn-packages" ></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Short of using JavaScript to grab the users window size and get an image that matches that you need to use an image tag. Although, for what you're wanting, just using a background image and having it show more or less of itself is probably a good thing. You just need to get the part you want focused on positioned properly.

Comment: Can't be done, not with the restrictions you (or your client) is imposing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are unwilling to use an `img` element, this is simply not possible.

This is the *exact* reason CSS3 introduced `background-size`.

Comment: I hate accepting something is impossible to achieve, but in this case I have to. I've found a work-around that fits.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using simple CSS but you can resize your background image by a third party.